# How can I make my website look better?

Tags: html, css

So I have a website currently under development.. let me just first say that the domain name is NOT the name of the website or going to have any relation to it..

http://pandafi.com/

This site is currently in its early stages of building, and what I need help with is the color..

I can't really find any color for the register box that matches the background, and I'm not sure if these are the right colors to use at all..

Comment: imho you should use a gradient color for that stuff..:)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but your site consistently takes a full 12 seconds to render in Safari on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You can find great themes, search for hex colours and any of the themes that contain a certain colour on the site I have linked below - hope you find it to be of use.

http://kuler.adobe.com/

Answer (score 0):

[use a color scheme generator](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=html%20color%20scheme%20generator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

Hire a professional designer. It's their job to build great-looking designs.

Or get a free pre-built theme.